# Many-Many Relationship in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a many to many relationship defined in SQLAlchemy

```
tweet2user = db.Table('tweet2user',
db.Column('tweet_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.uid')),
db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tweets.uid'))
```

)

where tweet is

```
class Tweet(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'tweets'
uid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
tweet = db.Column(db.String(140))
sentiment = db.Column(db.String(100))
sentimentValue = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

and the relevant part of user is

```
class User(db.Model):
    tweets = db.relationship('Tweet', secondary=tweet2user,
         backref=db.backref('tweets', lazy='dynamic'))
```

Now im new to Flask/SQLAlchemy/Python so this is how im trying to add to the relationship

```
    for item in data:
    tweetText = item['tweet']
    sentiment = item['data']['type']
    sentimentValue = item['data']['score']
    tweet = Tweet(tweetText,sentiment,str(sentimentValue))
    tweets.append(tweet)


if 'email' not in session:
    return redirect(url_for('signin'))
user = User.query.filter_by(email = session['email']).first()
user.tweets = tweets
db.session.commit()
```

However this gives me an error saying my foreign key constraints have been violated.
What am I doing wrong do I need to add the Tweets to my tweets table before making this relation.

also what is the diffrence between

```
class ClassName(db.Model)
```

and

```
class ClassName(Base)
```

Comment: The difference between `Base` and `db.Model` is that you typically create your own `Base` if you are just using SQLAlchemy. However, Flask-SQLAlchemy has already created a `Base` class for you to use so that it can know about your classes, and has even tweaked it so that that when you use `User.query` you get some additional methods (such as the `get_or_404` method) that are not part of the SQLAlchemy package. See the Flask-SQLAlchemy [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html#models) for more info on these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Found my error

```
tweet2user = db.Table('tweet2user',
db.Column('tweet_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.uid')) <<<...matching to wrong table haha,
db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tweets.uid')) <<<...same here
)
```